# Thread 'main' panicked at 'could not initialize thread_rng: All entropy sources failed

Tags: random, rust, arm, entropy, raspberry-pi-zero

After running a cross-compiled Rust ARM binary on a Raspberry Pi Zero for a few hours, the process panics with the following error:

```
1 Feb 02 12:03:17 raspberrypi monitoring-service[339]: thread 'main'
 panicked at 'could not initialize thread_rng: All entropy sources failed (permanently unavailable); cause: getrandom not ready (not ready
yet); cause: Resource temporarily unavailable (os error 11)', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.6.1/src/rngs/thread.rs:82:17
```

systemd tried to restart the process, but it failed with the same error several times. The next day I was able to manually restart it, but countdown to when it fails again.

I suspect this is caused by the [ws websocket crate](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs) indirectly using the [rand v0.6.1 crate](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.1/rand/), but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to force these packages to use a newer version of the rand crate, or do I need to tweak an OS setting on Raspbian? I'm running Raspbian Stretch (v9), kernel v4.14.79+. As an internal monitoring tool, my application requires no encryption or privacy so ideally I can get around the entropy issue.

Comment: First off: the websocket crates [`uses rand = "0.4.2"`](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs/blob/3722d1cd80763523debbe2f756e220a70b6436e2/Cargo.toml#L25), second you could make a PR at that repo to update the crand crate. If that takes too long, patch it yourself and [tell cargo to use your patch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-patch-section)

Comment: this happens because your program requests too many numbers from /dev/urandom. You can either fix the program (which might be not so trivial) or just add faster entropy sources to your system. Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rng-tools (it specifically mentions raspberry pi) and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haveged

Comment: @Laney but IIRC `/dev/urandom` doesn't block if it has no more entropy but just puts out "non secure randomness", in contrast to `/dev/random`.

Comment: I guess the real problem is, that it isn't websockets fault, but yours @Petrus, because as already said, the crate uses a different version of rand, which does not cover your error message. It may be your code? You may try any of the [other RNGs](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/index.html) rand provides.

Comment: Thank you @Laney! rng-tools seems to have fixed the problem. Busy doing a long-running test. If you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it tomorrow :).